# Apply CSS on a specific p:dataTable component instead of on all p:dataTable components

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have multiple datatables on the request form. I want to remove the border for all the datatables except for one. I have used the below style to remove the border. 
Can you please let me know how can I get only one datatable with borders. As of now, it removes the border for all datatables.

```css
.ui-datatable .ui-datatable-data td, .ui-datatable .ui-datatable-data-empty td {
  border-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Give the table in question a specific style class:

```xhtml
<p:dataTable ... styleClass="borderless">
```

So that you can use more specific CSS selectors for this:

```css
.ui-datatable.borderless .ui-datatable-data tr,
.ui-datatable.borderless .ui-datatable-data-empty tr,
.ui-datatable.borderless .ui-datatable-data td,
.ui-datatable.borderless .ui-datatable-data-empty td {
    border-style: none;
}
```

*(note that I extended the selector to cover `tr` as well; it has by default also a border, your initial selector removes only the vertical border between the columns, not the horizontal border between the rows)*

#### See also:

- [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-those-classes-defined-in-primefaces-css/8774997#8774997)

Comment: Very helpful! But in my case, it doesnt't work for the column headers. They still have borders.

Comment: @Turbokiwi: the question was not how to remove *all* borders from a datatable, but the question was how to apply the given CSS on a specific datatable instead of *all* datatables.

Comment: @BalusC It doesn't work for me. All borders still appearing. I am using primefaces 3.5

Comment: @JohnB: the question was not how to remove *all* borders from a datatable, but the question was how to apply the given CSS on a specific datatable instead of *all* datatables. I have updated the question title accordingly.

Comment: @BalusC I published a question about that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880208/remove-all-border-on-a-specific-datatable) Could you help me please?