# Remove all borders on a specific datatable

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, datatable, border

I need to hide all borders of one datatable, not all, using PrimeFaces. I have tried many things and no one has worked. Does anyone know how to do it?

I have applied the following styles (separately) to the `ui-datatable` class:

```css
border: hidden !important;    
border-style: none !important;
```

And another things...

Comment: Please post your code, and show which table you want to change.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Assuming a PrimeFaces 3.5 data table which is marked up as follows,

```html
<p:dataTable ... styleClass="borderless">
```

then this style should do:

```css
.ui-datatable.borderless thead th,
.ui-datatable.borderless tbody,
.ui-datatable.borderless tbody tr,
.ui-datatable.borderless tbody td {
    border-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

with JSF 2, PrimeFaces 3.5

```html
<p:dataTable ... styleClass="borderless">
```

css:

```
.borderless .ui-datatable thead th,
.borderless .ui-datatable tbody,
.borderless .ui-datatable tbody tr,
.borderless .ui-datatable tbody td {
    border: none;
    display: none;
}
```

for datatable header:

```
.borderless .ui-state-default,
.borderless .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default,
.borderless .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
    border: none;
}
```